# Is it possible to suppress label cowplot package R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I was wondering if it is possible to suppress the axis label at (x - top: "mpg") and (y - right: "wt") using the package cowplot.

```
library(ggplot2); library(cowplot)  
plot_a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,wt)) + geom_point()  
ggdraw(switch_axis_position(plot_a, axis = 'xy',keep = 'xy'))
```

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: https://rdrr.io/cran/cowplot/man/panel_border.html

Substitute your `ggdraw` line for:
`plot+panel_border(colour="black", size=0.5, linetype=1,remove=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
# devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
# packageVersion("ggplot2")
# # [1] ‘2.1.0.9001’

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .)) + 
  cowplot::theme_cowplot()
```

[image]

Check the notes on [`ggplot2 2.2.0`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/09/30/ggplot2-2-2-0-coming-soon/).

Comment: Great answer, and thanks for the updates on ggplot2!